# Not able to run unit tests on kotlin Multiplatform project

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, junit4

I am trying to create a kotlin Multiplatform library which can later convert into java and javascript using  IDEA 2019.3, kotlin 1.3 .

I created  a simple junit (4) test class and configured it as follows.

```
package sample;
import org.junit.Test;

public class Tests {
    @Test
    public void test1(){
        System.out.println("here");
    }

}
```

[image]
 But while running, it’s failing with

> Process finished with exit code 1 Class not found: "sample.DummyTest"

I could not figure out what am I doing wrong. Please advice.

Answer (score 2):

check your name of class test, it could be: com.package.example.Tests
or click right on your class and make the configuration:

[image]

if you want to run all test (included unitest from implements modules) in your project, create this configuration:

[image]

in your gradle dependencies check this import

```
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but it did not really help